# How to enable the Core database on a CD server in Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: installation

Even if it's not mandatory for this version, I'd like to enable the Core database to troubleshoot a few issues I'm having in staging.

How is this done?

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: Follow up: what do you need to troubleshoot that requires a core DB on the CD?  I am assuming Sitecore 9.1. If thats the case, the core DB isn't utilized on the CD. So if you're having issues with account or login, thats all identity server. So even adding the core db to the CD isn't going to help you with accounts. Just curious what the real question is.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for comment. We have this legacy module that is supposed to work on 9.1 and is still using the Core db so being able to enable/disable this database would help me identifying and fixing all the old dependencies that I need to get rid of.

Comment: Ahh! Got it. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend this, but in your Sitecore.config remove the `role:require="!ContentDelivery"` from these three sections. It will bring core back. I don't think Sitecore will like it as the ContentDelivery does a lot of stuff.

```
<eventQueue name="core" type="Sitecore.Data.Eventing.$(database)EventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="!ContentDelivery">
  <param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
  <param ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(name)']" />
</eventQueue>

<store name="core" prefix="core" getValueWithoutPrefix="true" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Properties.$(database)PropertyStore, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="!ContentDelivery">
  <param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
  <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseEventManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseCacheManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</store>


<database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="!ContentDelivery">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <connectionStringName>$(id)</connectionStringName>
    <icon>Images/database_core.png</icon>
    <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
    <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
        <prefetch role:require="ContentManagement or Standalone" hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Core.config" />
        </prefetch>
    </dataProvider>
    </dataProviders>
    <PropertyStore ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(id)']" />
    <remoteEvents.EventQueue>
    <obj ref="eventing/eventQueueProvider/eventQueue[@name='$(id)']" />
    </remoteEvents.EventQueue>
    <workflowProvider hint="defer" type="Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.WorkflowProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="database">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="history store" ref="workflowHistoryStores/main" param1="$(id)" />
    </workflowProvider>
    <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
    <archive name="archive" />
    <archive name="recyclebin" />
    </archives>
    <cacheSizes hint="setting">
    <data>100MB</data>
    <items>50MB</items>
    <paths>2500KB</paths>
    <itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
    <standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
    </cacheSizes>
    <NotificationProvider type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.$(database).$(database)NotificationProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param connectionStringName="$(id)">
    </param>
    <param desc="databaseName">$(id)</param>
    </NotificationProvider>
</database>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, will definitely try that.