# Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='core'] in content delivery server

Tags: content-delivery

I keep getting the below error in sitecore CD servers every 5 seconds time.Is there any way to stop this error from happening.We dont use core DB for any security membership or for any login ourposes.But still we are getting this error very often.

```
ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='core']
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.get_Database()
at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context)
at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.​⁫‏⁫‭⁯‬‌⁬‪⁯‫⁭‭⁬‏‭‫​‍​⁮⁮‮⁪‬‭‪⁮‏‍⁬​‏‫‎‮​⁭‫‮(Object , EventArgs )
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: This issue is related to some config issue, do you have core DB reference in connectionstring.config?

Comment: Hi Surya Thank you so much for your answer,Is there a way to find that specific function or code, I have tried but I couldnt able to locate it.

Comment: Hi Yes, we have core DB reference in connectionstring config file.

Comment: Did you try this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18217/how-to-enable-the-core-database-on-a-cd-server-in-sitecore-9-1/18220#18220

Comment: Gaurav , No i didn't try that , because the reason for hesitation since its not recommended by sitecore. So we dont want want to take that risk. So if we can able to locate particular code where we call core DB as reference, then it will be useful for us.

Comment: If you can try, then try to disable custom configs one by one and identify which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Try defining Role in the config

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your content delivery server is trying to access core database and core database is not enabled on CD servers.

To fix this, you need to either find specific config/code/task which is calling "core" database and handle it accordingly or you should enable core database on content delivery by applying this [patch](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/18220/1606) . By the way enabeling core database on CD servers are not recommended.

Comment: Surya Thank you so much for your answer, Is there a way to find that specific function or code, I have tried but I couldn't able to locate it.

Comment: @Jay Search for "Core" in your entire solution and also in showconfig.aspx. You might find code/custom config referring to core db.

Comment: Side note: this also applies to the `master` database.